# How to validate Date type column value in SharePoint list?

Tags: date-time

I have date column in SharePoint list, which is basically for a license file application. So I want that the user cannot select date unless and **until he is 18+ years**.

What formula do I need to apply for this ?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: And what have you thought of to accomplish the task so far? How do you know the age of the user: user profile property, another column specifying the date of birth, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not sure that can you achieve this using validation formulas but you can achieve this using [SPUtility.js](https://sputility.codeplex.com/)

1.Edit "Edit item" form of your list in browser.
2. Add Script editor web part.
3. Add the following script in script editor and save.

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sputility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var ageValue= SPUtility.GetSPField('AGE').GetValue();
var dateField=SPUtility.GetSPField('DATE');
if(ageValue<18)
{
dateField.MakeReadOnly();
}
else
{
dateField.MakeEditable();
}
});
</script>
```

SPUtility.js is a JavaScript library used to make modifications to SharePoint's list forms (NewForm.aspx, DispForm and EditForm.aspx in a survey, custom list or library). It works with SharePoint 2007, 2010, and 2013 (including SharePoint Online / Office 365).

Look SPUtility.js documentation for more details.